# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPLIANCE-FAQ\resources\views\askQuestions\show.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-6

I use laravel and my project has a back part and a front on the back side all works but on the front side I find it difficult to make information accessible with this functionality. my controller is as follows:

```
public function show(AskQuestion $ask_questions, Respone $respone)
{
    $ask_questions = AskQuestion::with(['email', 'objet_question', 'text_question', 'respone'])
        ->whereId($ask_questions)
        ->first();

    //$ask_questions->timestamps = false;
    //$ask_questions->views_count++;
    //$ask_questions->save();

    return view('askQuestions.show', compact('ask_questions'));
}
```

here my layoutcomposer.php

```
 public function compose(View $view)
{
    /*bind the asked question to view*/
    $view->with('latestQuestions', AskQuestion::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get());
    /*binding the response to the view*/
    $view->with('latestRespones', Respone::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get());
    /************/
    $view->with('popularArticles', Article::orderBy('views_count', 'desc')->take(6)->get());
    $view->with('latestArticles', Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(6)->get());
    $view->with('popularTags', Tag::withCount('articles')->orderBy('articles_count', 'desc')->take(20)->get());
    $view->with('footerCategories', Category::take(6)->get());
}
```

here my show.blade.php

```
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header alert alert-primary">
                {{-- $ask_questions->id --}}
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <hr>
                <marquee>
                    <strong><p>Veuillez noter votre degré de satisfaction une fois que vous aurez la réponse à votre question svp!</p></strong>
                </marquee>
                <p>&nbsp</p>

                <div class="fat-content-small padding-left-10">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($ask_questions as $ask_question)
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('askQuestions.show', [$ask_question->id, $ask_question->email, $ask_question->text_question]) }}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> {{ $ask_question->objet_question }}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And with all these bugs I had to use a view compose but nothing bugs persist there I do not know what to do I really need help please

Comment: `dd($ask_questions)` in your controller to see what it returns. (I guess nothing because the parameter `$ask_questions` is a class and `->whereId($ask_questions)` should fail)

Comment: The reason is that `$ask_questions` should be empty. Just `dd($ask_questions)` and if its null then that the problem

Comment: you're right it's null